# How to read .txt file without .readlines() / replace UTF-8 newline character with \n?

Tags: python, web.py

I have some AI-generated nonsense in a .txt file that looks like this:

```
MENENIUS:
I have been they prayers of the reason,
And away to friends than the state pointer;
The words that shall can virtue to your head.
```

I have some Python code (using [web.py](http://webpy.org/tutorial3.en)) that looks like this:

```
class index(object):
    def GET(self):
        text = open("menenius.txt", "r").read() 
        return render.index(text)
```

When I view it in localhost, it looks like this:

```
MENENIUS: I have been they prayers of the reason, And away to friends than the state pointer; The words that shall can virtue to your head.
```

Menenius' little speech is actually just one clipping of a much larger .txt file, so I don't want to use `.readlines()` as going over the list will be memory-intensive. If that weren't an issue, in a normal script I'd be able to just print the list that `.readlines()` generates, but the fact that I'm using web.py and need to get this into `render.index()` complicates things.

### What I've Tried

My first thought was to use the `.replace()` method in the script that generates menenius.txt to replace every instance of the invisible UTF-8 newline character with `\n`. Since `.read()` gives you the entire .txt file as a single string, I thought that would work but doing this:

```
from_text = open("menenius.txt", "r").read()
from_text.replace(0x0A, "\n")
```

Gets me this error, referring to the line with `.replace()`:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Which I've googled, but none of it seems very applicable or very clear. I'm just starting out with Python and I've been going around in circles with this for a couple of hours, so I feel like there's something really obvious here that I don't know about.

---

As I mentioned I've also tried returning the list that `.readlines()` generates, but that's going to get memory-intensive and I'm not sure how to fit that output into `render.index()` anyway.

### Edit: The Solution

So the answer below works, but after I made that change I was still having the same issue. ShadowRanger's "I'm assuming your renderer is sending out HTML" got me thinking, and I opened up localhost and got into the web inspector to see that all the text was in quotation marks within its `p` tags, like so:

```
<p>
"MENENIUS: I have been they prayers of the reason, And away to friends than the state pointer; The words that shall can virtue to your head."
</p>
```

I came back to this after a few hours having realised something. In the `index.html` file the content was being sent to, it looked like this:

```
<p>
$content
</p>
```

I had a suspicion, checked the [web.py intro tutorial](http://webpy.org/tutorial3.en) again and found this:

> As you can see, the templates look a lot like Python files except for the def with statement at the top (saying what the template gets called with) and the $s placed in front of any code. Currently, template.py requires the $def statement to be the first line of the file. Also, note that web.py automatically escapes any variables used here, so that if for some reason name is set to a value containing some HTML, it will get properly escaped and appear as plain text. If you want to turn this off, write $:name instead of $name.

I changed `$content` to `$:content`, and suddenly the text is being rendered as HTML rather than as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file already contains newlines (`'\x0a'` is an escape for the exact same character that `'\n'` produces). I'm assuming your renderer is sending out HTML though, and HTML doesn't care about newlines in the text (outside of `pre` blocks, and other blocks styled similarly).

So either wrap the data in a `pre` block, or replace the `'\n'` with `<br>` tags (which are how HTML says "No, really, I want a line break"), e.g.:

```
from_text = from_text.replace("\n", "<br>\n")
```

Leaving in the newlines may be handy to people viewing the source, so I replaced with both the `<br>` tag and a newline (Python won't replace in a replacement, so don't worry about infinite replacement just because the newline was part of the replacement).

Comment: That worked, combined with the edit I've made to the original post. Thanks!